# Update: Magento 1 checkout account create redirect, SUPEE-10570v2 and Magento 1.9.3.9

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, customer-account, redirect, supee-10570

We currently have a strange problem on our Magento 1.9.3.9 shop.

When someone fills in the password fields in the checkout, to create an account. In that case when clicking the place order button on the checkout review page, it redirects to the homepage instead of the PSP.

It does create an account and place the order in the backend, but the customer is not re-directed to the payment page of the PSP.

UPDATE:

Someone told us it could be related to the SUPEE-10570v1 patch, that could cause this problem. Magento released SUPEE-10570v2 that should solve it. But we are running Magento 1.9.3.9 which should include the SUPEE-10570v2.

But for some reason Magento revert the changes from SUPEE-10570v2 inside SUPEE-10752.

When we are checking the SUPEE-10570v2 .sh file, we see the following lines:

```
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php
@@ -235,9 +235,8 @@ class Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstra
      */
     public function changePassword(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer, $newPassword)
     {
-        $customer->setPassword($newPassword)->setPasswordCreatedAt(time());
+        $customer->setPassword($newPassword);
         $this->saveAttribute($customer, 'password_hash');
-        $this->saveAttribute($customer, 'password_created_at');
         return $this;
     }
```

That means it removes the lines with the - sign and add the lines with the + sign. So the new file should not have the lines:

```
$customer->setPassword($newPassword)->setPasswordCreatedAt(time());
$this->saveAttribute($customer, 'password_created_at');
```

But when we check the file `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php` of the default Magento 1.9.3.9 install, we see the following:

```
public function changePassword(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer, $newPassword)
{
    $customer->setPassword($newPassword)->setPasswordCreatedAt(time());
    $this->saveAttribute($customer, 'password_hash');
    $this->saveAttribute($customer, 'password_created_at');
    return $this;
}
```

The problem still exists even on a fresh and clean install of Magento 1.9.3.9. 
But when we apply SUPEE-10570v2 over Magento 1.9.3.9, the problem is solved. But the code of Magento 1.9.3.9 is newer and should include the right version of SUPEE-10570.

So we are a bit confused. What should we do in this case? Is this still a Magento bug that they should solve? Any help in here.

Comment: I also have this issue...... If you do find it can you let me know please

Comment: Please check the network activity in the developer console and show us the result which shows right after clicking at the button.

Comment: are you asking to fix or why didn't magento include this in the latest release?

Comment: @Haim Both, but mainly to ask why they did not include the v2 fix in the next releases.

Comment: @HenkZ see my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

Apparently it was never added even in [1.9.3.10](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/blob/1.9.3.x/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php) , it seems that the community support for M1 is really dwindling so I'm not sure if this will ever be fixed :-(

You can try reporting it [here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/issues/522)

Edit: as per Haim's answer this bug should no longer be present in `1.9.3.9` however the lines that were removed in SUPEE-10570v2 should be removed from magento's main repo.

Comment: you were wrong :( - look at my updated answer, they fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know why Magento didn't include the v2 fix in the next release, then @yehuda's answer is correct. 
As a matter of fact they didn't even add it to the 1.9.4 release - that file is the same as the 1.9.3.10 release - see [here](https://github.com/treestonemedia/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9.4/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php)

To fix your issue - you just need to manually apply that piece of the patch.
Replace the  `changePassword` function in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php` on line 236

```
public function changePassword(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer, $newPassword)
{
    $customer->setPassword($newPassword)->setPasswordCreatedAt(time());
    $this->saveAttribute($customer, 'password_hash');
    $this->saveAttribute($customer, 'password_created_at');
    return $this;
}
```

with this

```
    public function changePassword(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer, $newPassword)
{
    $customer->setPassword($newPassword);
    $this->saveAttribute($customer, 'password_hash');
    return $this;
}
```

You should always make such changes in the locla directory, so

- First copy `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php`
- Then change the `changePassword` function and you'll be set.

**UPDATE**

I was 100% wrong - Magento fixed it. Here's how:

in  `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php` they added at line 732 to 734

```
    $passwordCreatedTime = $this->_checkoutSession->getData('_session_validator_data')['session_expire_timestamp']
        - Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie')->getLifetime();
    $customer->setPasswordCreatedAt($passwordCreatedTime);
```

Make sure that your code (magento 1.9.3.9) has that in there and you should be set.

- I tested it on a clean magento 1.9.3.8 and got the bug
- I tested it on a clean magento 1.9.3.9 and did not get the bug
- I tested it on a magento 1.9.3.9 with those three lines commented out and got the bug

Comment: Many thanks Haim! We are running 1.9.3.9 with the 'updated' Onepage.php file, these lines are already there, but still facing the issue. When creating an account in the checkout, customers are redirected to the homepage.

Comment: Are you using the default Magento one page checkout?

Comment: Yes, we are running the default Magento checkout.

Comment: very strange - any modules on? did you apply any of the patches? something is causing this behavior but I don't think it's the issue you initially thought it was i.e patch SUPEE-10570v2

Comment: Yes it is, we already applied all default code of 1.9.3.9 and that also did not work. Issue is still there. I know, but I really can not find the problem. The main problem is that the log's are also empty, so it is really hard to debug. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Got this problem again after updating from 1.9.4.1 to 1.9.4.3, is there a fix?
The problem is it doesn't happend all the time and there are no errors in log!

Comment: @HenkZ did you find the problem?

Comment: Find the issue, the password_created_at (attribute_code) in the database eav_attribute was set to entity_type_id 10 instead of 1. Got no idea what rigger this change in de database. Set it back to ID 1 and problem is solved

Comment: Thanks @Mike! Did it solve the problem entirely?

Comment: @HenkZ The problem has come back and see in the database that the entity_type_id from the password_created_at (attribute_code) in the database eav_attribute has been set back to 10 instead of 1 again. No idea by what this is being triggered in Magento. But when I put the entity_type_id back on ID 1, the problem is gone.
And as answer to your question whether it has been entirely solved, yes after the correct setting of this ID it is solved.